# qmath very strange AttributeError

Tags: python, quaternions

I'm trying to use qmath, a quaternion lib.

this

```
from qmath import  qmathcore
a = qmathcore.quaternion([1,2,3,4])
print a.conj()
```

gives me such traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "*******/q_test.py", line 25, in <module>
    print str(a.conj())
  File "*******/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qmath/qmathcore.py", line 788, in conj
    return self.real() - self.imag()
  File "*******/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qmath/qmathcore.py", line 762, in imag
    return self - self.real()      
  File "*******/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qmath/qmathcore.py", line 522, in __sub__
    self -= other
  File "*******/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qmath/qmathcore.py", line 407, in __isub__
    self.other = quaternion(other)
  File "*******/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qmath/qmathcore.py", line 81, in __init__
    self.q = q.q
AttributeError: quaternion instance has no attribute 'q'
```

but in docs they said, that this must work:

```
def conj(self):
    """
    Returns the conjugate of the quaternion
    >>> import qmathcore
    >>> a = qmathcore.quaternion([1,2,3,4])
    >>> a.conj()
    (1.0-2.0i-3.0j-4.0k)
    >>> a = qmathcore.hurwitz([1,2,3,4])
    >>> a.conj()
    (1-2i-3j-4k)
    """
    return self.real() - self.imag()
```

what is this?

Comment: BTW, does anyone know a good quaternion python lib? I've tried `qmath` (see question), `Quaternion` (can't work with unnormalized Qs) and `euclid` which has very heavy scipy in dependencies but can't multiply Qs and vectors, and `quaternionarray` which does not even imports. This is sad.

Comment: This `qmath.quaternion(np.float64(1))` produces the same error. `qmath.quaternion(np.float(1))` works fine.  I suspect a change in `numpy` in the 2 years since `qmath` was written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`qmathcore.py` fails its own doctest with a newer (1.9) numpy.

Adding this test to `quatereon()`

```
    elif isinstance(q,float) or isinstance(q,int): # accept np.float64
        self.q = 1.0 * np.array([q,0.,0.,0.])
```

allows `qmath.quaternion([1,2,3,4]).imag()`  (and `conj`).

The `quaternion` method is using a lot of `type(q)==xxx` tests.  `isinstance()` is a more robust test.  Also it ends with a `else:pass`, and thus doesn't catch `q` values that it can't handle.

After correcting some import errors, the `qmathcore` doctest runs fine.

Comment: Im not sure that this is THE ANSWER, but accepted. In my project Ive implemented own version of quaternion algebra. But still.. many thanks for your answer!

Comment: I've been looking at `qmath` some more.  That math appears to be ok, but the handling of Python classes, especially subclassing `quaternion` is crude.  The emphasis seems to be on handling a variety of input formats, rather than making something useful for further calculation.